How to add a textbox in CommandBarControl in right click context menu in Excel VBA
I have below VBA code which adds an option with sub-options in the right click context menu in worksheet. It contains the line which I expected to create a textbox.
Set Ctrl = Application.CommandBars(CmdBars(i)).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=1, Temporary:=True)

The Complete Code:
Const MyToolMenuNm = "My Options"
Sub AddRightClickContextMenu()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
DeleteRightClickContextMenu
Dim Ctrl As CommandBarControl
Dim Btn As CommandBarControl
CmdBars = Split("Cell|Row|Column|List Range Popup", "|")
ListOfProceduresInMyToolsModule = Array(Array("Option 1", "Macro1"), Array("Option 2", "Macro2"), Array("Option 3", "Macro3"))
For i = LBound(CmdBars) To UBound(CmdBars)
    Set Ctrl = Application.CommandBars(CmdBars(i)).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=1, Temporary:=True)
    Ctrl.Caption = MyToolMenuNm
    With Ctrl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlEdit)
        .Caption = "Search the menus"
        .OnAction = "FilterMenus"
    End With
    For j = LBound(ListOfProceduresInMyToolsModule) To UBound(ListOfProceduresInMyToolsModule)
        With Ctrl.Controls.Add
            .Caption = GetAccessKey(j + 1) & ". " & ListOfProceduresInMyToolsModule(j)(0)
            .OnAction = ListOfProceduresInMyToolsModule(j)(1)
        End With
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
Function GetAccessKey(num As Integer)
If num <= 9 Then
    GetAccessKey = "&" & Chr(num + 48)
Else
    GetAccessKey = "&" & Chr(num + 55)
End If
End Function
Sub DeleteRightClickContextMenu()
On Error Resume Next
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(MyToolMenuNm).Delete
Application.CommandBars("Row").Controls(MyToolMenuNm).Delete
Application.CommandBars("Column").Controls(MyToolMenuNm).Delete
Application.CommandBars("List Range Popup").Controls(MyToolMenuNm).Delete

End Sub

I am expecting a textbox with the placeholder text "Search the menus" before the "1. Option 1" option which should be similar to the "Search the menus" text box above "My Options". But it is not visible or not created.

